# Помогите решить задачу для курсовой с массивами в JS

Tags: javascript

```
Условие задачи:
Задать с клавиатуры размер массива (в диапазоне [1; 100]):
 - заполнить его числами случайным образом (в диапазоне [-50.00; 50.00])
 - найти минимальный элемент массива
 - найти максимальный элемент массива
 - найти среднее арифметическое элементов массива.

Для многих это может показаться бредом, но я новичок и полный 0 в js и пока это то что мне удалось сделать. Разбила на разные циклы так мне проще хоть что-то понять.


//Задать с клавиатуры размер массива в диапазоне 1; 100

  

  System.out.print("Введите размер массива: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[size];
    int [] array2 = new  int [2];
    array2[0] = 1;
    array2[1] = 100;

//Заполнить числами случайным образом в диапазоне -50,00; 50.00

 

   double a = -50.00;
    double b = 50.00;
    Random random = new Random();
    double floatArray = a + random.nextDouble() * (b - a);
    System.out.println(" " + floatArray);

//Найти минимальный елемент массива


 

   System.out.println("Минимальное значение массива: ");

// Найти максимальный елемент массива
 

     int max = 100;
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if (array[(int) i] >= max) {
              max = array[(int) i];
          }

        System.out.println("Максимальное значение массива: ");

//Найти среднеарифметический елементов массива

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        double avg = sum / array.length;
        System.out.println("Сренднеарифметическое елементов массива: " + avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересный у вас javascript, однако.

Comment: Поясните к чему здесь js. Сообщение вверху ничего не объясняет. Отвечать можно на любом языке?

Comment: Решить задачу необходимо на js  с применением переменной double

Comment: В js кроме double ничего и нет, кроме совсем редких случаев типа работы с бинарными операторами, где числа на время становятся интами.

Comment: Как объяснил куратор нам и нужно построить решение на double

Comment: Если речь про js, то такое уточнение просто не имеет смысла )

Comment: @novichok Я не уверен, что то, что написано от вас выше - это  javaScript.

Comment: Я вам больше скажу я не уверена, что то, что написано от меня выше хоть на какой то язык похож. А если серьезно, я сделала наброски из пройденного материала, на котором я отсутствовала, и попыталась подставить значения из условий задачи, но как видите у меня это не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил эту задачу вот таким образом на javaScript, применив его интересные хаки и возможности. Может, как вариант тоже - подсмотреть, подойдет.

Однако хаки не для прям и новичка, преподаватель может задать вопросы по решению, нужно быть к этому готовым.

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const getObjectData = () => {
  const numbers = [];
  let arrayLength = 1;
  do {
    arrayLength = +prompt('диапазон должен быть [1; 100]');
  } while (arrayLength > 100 || arrayLength <= 0);

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (numbers.length === 50) break;
    numbers.push(getRandom(-50, 50));
  }

  const sum = numbers.reduce((acc, number) => acc + number);

  return {
    min: Math.min(...numbers),
    max: Math.max(...numbers),
    average: sum / numbers.length,
  };
};

const { min, max, average } = getObjectData();

console.group('getObjectData');
console.log(`минимальный элемент массива ${min}`);
console.log(`максимальный элемент массива ${max}`);
console.log(`среднее арифметическое элементов массива ${average}`);
console.groupEnd();
```

Answer (score 4):

Это медвежья услуга конечно и спецом не "в распространённом духе js", чтобы было заметно при проверке, но как вариант для "подсмотреть":

```js
let length = prompt( 'Введите размер массива от 1 до 100', 1 );
if( isNaN(length) || !isFinite(length) ) length = 1;
length = Math.round(length);
if( length < 1 ) length = 1;
if( length > 100 ) length = 100;

let arr = new Array(length);
let min = Infinity;
let max = -Infinity;
let total = 0;

for( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
  let value = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
  arr[i] = value;
  if( value < min ) min = value;
  if( value > max ) max = value;
  total += value;
}

let mean = total / length;

console.log( 'array', arr );
console.log( 'min', min );
console.log( 'max', max );
console.log( 'mean', mean );
```

Comment: И на этом огромное спасибо   

Comment: @Leonid Почему не в духе js?

Comment: Может потому что лучше `Array.from({length:length})` или `Array.apply(null, {length:length})` использовать вместо `new Array(length)` , но лучше у автора ответа спросить... ))

Comment: @WalkMess Потому что сейчас мода на преобразование массивов из одного состояния в другое в угоду читабельности. Например задача "найти максимальный элемент массива" в моём примере выполнена не совсем верно по смыслу, так как я с элементами массива ничего не делал, не применял какой-нибудь `reduce`.

Comment: Те, кто пишет например на реакте с редаксом, такие циклы не пишут, у них функциональные преобразования.